# How to avoid crash of a .NET exe when a termination error occurred in powershell script execution that has invoked using Powershell.Invoke()

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

The following code invokes a powershell script and when the script breaks due to a termination error from powershell script such as "Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'ActiveDirectory' provider failed." catches the exception but the .NET app crashes.

```
try
{
 output = this.PowerShellEnvironment.Invoke();
}
 catch (CmdletInvocationException ex)
{ 
}
catch (RuntimeException ex)
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  try
{
 output = this.PowerShellEnvironment.Invoke();
}
 catch (Exception ex)
{ 
//handle ex here
}
```

use following code get the excpetion type and do the operation you want to perform (handle exception etc..) in catch block

Comment: The code in the question already has `catch (Exception ex)` with an empty block, and the question says the app still crashes.